# Como consultar aplicativos em execução no windows através do python?

Tags: funções

a minha aplicação é criar um programa em python que identifique que o software x ou y esta aberto no sistema operacional, ou que me retorne uma lista de softwares em execução no sistema operacional. Tentei algumas soluções através da busca de por lista de processos, mas sem sucesso. Alguém pode me ajudar?

A ideia é que eu depois desenvolva algo tipo: "Se o programa X estiver aberto, faça isso. Se o programa Y estiver aberto, faça outra coisa."

Answer (score 0):

import psutil
import json

outlook = json.dumps({"name": "OUTLOOK.EXE"})

for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
#print(proc.info)
input = json.dumps(proc.info)
if input==outlook:
print('Outlook aberto')